# How to keep spare hard drive from spinning up all the time on windows system?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, power-management

I have a large drive on my windows 10 desktop I use for nightly backups.  It only needs to run during the backup time, otherwise, I'd prefer it spin down and be off.  I have it set to spin down in power management settings.  I realize windows likes to randomly access everything for no reason so I have a script that unmounts the drive (remove drive letter) after the back up (and remount it when the backup starts).  Monitoring the drive,  see no reads/writes to the drive.  However, even after doing this, I still hear the drive spin up every couple hours.

Comment: Bring your disk offline and online using script. That should help too.

Comment: A good quality HDD spins happily, makes no noise, and without damage.  If you are very concerned, change it for a large SSD  which will not spin.

Comment: Put it inside an external enclosure and power it off when not required.

Comment: LPChip: when you say "bring your disk offline and online using a script" what do you mean?  how do I bring it "offline"?  I an unmounting it using a script but that doesnt stop the drive from starting up.

Comment: harrymc: I thought of this option but the computer I have it connected to is over and doesnt support any external interface that is as fast as SATA.  I guess it doesnt matter if the backup takes a little longer.  It's still a bit of a clunky workaround

Comment: You can add a simple switch in the power connection to the HDD, though that would require you remember to close the switch before nightly backup. Actually, occasional startup of a HDD can prevent "stiction", where there is high initial startup friction in bearings -- though if you use it daily, stiction would not be an issue.

Comment: I don't think daily is a big deal, but every hour or so seems excessive.  Yes I know I can install a switch or something.  On another system, I'm using and external drive and have the power hooked to a timer for power.  This case, I don't have that option.  I suspect windows might be rescanning for new hardware or something every now and then causing the spinup

Answer (score 0):

Software-wise I don't see a solution as it's difficult to distinguish between a legitimate spin-up command and an unwanted one.

Put that backup drive in an external USB 3.0 case.
That leaves you the option to either

**a)**
switch off the drive
advantage: no power consumption, not exposed to mains surges when using a two-pole switch in-between, not exposed to viral oder ransomware activity when being offline
disadvantage: 1 spin-up per backup

**b)**
disconnect the USB connection (maybe using a USB hub with power switches)
advantage: disk will go into sleep mode sometime, no complete shutdown
disadvantage: standby power consumption, electronics get used over time (maybe internal switching regulator), mains surge exposure